# how can i get single value from firebase realtime database for ionic

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

```
async incrementTuts(key) {
 let newData= {'tutsApplied':this.tutsApplied+1} 
 let newInfo = firebase.database().ref('thisis/'+this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('key')).update(newData);
}
```

I want to increment tutsApplied on firebase realtime database using ionic 4. how can i acheive that.

Corrected image:

update:

i have used

```
let key = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('key');
let ref = firebase.database().ref(`thisis/${key}/tutsApplied`);
ref.transaction((current) => {
  return (current || 0) + 1;
});
```

but new field is created  under undefined as shown in image. i dont want to create new field. and how can i print current value in console?

Comment: what are you getting now?

Comment: Well, that code won't work as it's attempting to access `tutsApplied` when the actual child name in Firebase is `tusApplied`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking to write a new value for a property based on its current value. To do that, you'd [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).

Something like:

```
let key = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('key');
let ref = firebase.database().ref(`thisis/${key}/tutsApplied`);
ref.transaction((current) => {
  return (current || 0) + 1;
});
```

Comment: Typo in question; child is tusApplied

Comment: Good catch Jay. If that's indeed the cause of the problem, the question should probably be closed as a typo.